# GitHub authentification

Tags: git, github

I am using Github for some time now and I wanted to push a file on my personal repository on GitHub website but my access is always denied.
I am dong all the steps correctly I think in my terminal:

```
git init
git add file
git push -m 'first commit'
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/new_repo.git
git push -u origin main
```

After this, they ask for my username and my password
For my username I am using my username on GitHub and for the password I am using my personal access token (pat) but it is still not working.
It seems like they do not accept my password

Can someone help me on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have marked `repo` permission during creating the token. Also make sure you are generating a `classic` tokens.

Look at the image for more clarification:

[image]